# Adding headers to Cmake

Tags: compilation, cmake

I am trying to run the examples from VTK and modify them to get to what I want to render on screen.
I am currently trying to add a server application running in parallel to the VTK rendering. I already have my code written for the server but I was wondering how I could add these headers and cpp to CMakeLists.txt.

Indeed, this is the CMakeLists.txt I have so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(RotateActor)

option(INCLUDE_SERVER
  "Use the server implementation" ON)

# add the Server library?
if (INCLUDE_SERVER)
    include_directories({${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Server/})
    set(SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Server/tcp_server.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Server/tcp_server.h)
endif (INCLUDE_SERVER)


find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(RotateActor MACOSX_BUNDLE RotateActor ${SOURCES})

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
    target_link_libraries(RotateActor ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
    target_link_libraries(RotateActor vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()
```

I then generate using CMake and VS2012. When opening the sln file and trying to generate I get the following error so I'm guessing my integration of the headers is not correct.

```
C:\...\RotateActor.cxx(12): fatal error C1083: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier include : 'tcp_server.h' : No such file or directory
```

I don't think you need the RotateActor.cxx file, but if you do let me know.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't see `RotateActor.cxx` being mentioned in the CMakeLists.txt; is tcp_server.cpp really located in the `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}`? why?

Comment: You're right it had no reasons to be there and was actually not. I edited the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some problems in your CMake file. First of all, your `*.h` files musn't be given in the `add_executable` command. Try something like that :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(RotateActor)
option(INCLUDE_SERVER "Use the server implementation" ON)

# Manage your libraries before your sources
find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

# add the Server library ?
# Here, maybe use the path from the root, and not from the local dir ?
# Don't add the .h in the sources
if(INCLUDE_SERVER)
  include_directories({${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Server})
  set(RotateActor_CPP_SOURCES
    ${RotateActor_CPP_SOURCES}
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Server/tcp_server.cpp
  )
endif()

if(NOT VTK_LIBRARIES)
  set(VTK_LIBRARIES vtkHybrid vtkWidgets)
endif()

add_executable(RotateActor ${RotateActor_CPP_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(RotateActor ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Doesn't work though as I get "fatal error LNK1120: 1 external not resolved" error in visual studio and when looking at the additional include directories of the project I don't see the Server directory. Even when I add it manually, I still get the error. So is it possible to solve these two errors so that 1 I don't have to add it manually and 2 I don't get this other error? Thanks for the help so far :) Edit: now my Rotate.cxx file is not even included anymore in the VS project. So I'm guessing there's an other problem

Comment: What is your tree of directories, where do you launch cmake and with which command ?

Comment: I launch CMake with the GUI. RotateActor.cxx is at the root. From there I have Server/ and build/

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure to well understand your environment. Are you compiling with VisualStudio under Mac OS X ? It seems strange...

Comment: No i'm actually using Windows. I indeed wouldn't use VS on mac :)

Comment: Then, you try to produce a Mac executable under Windows ?

Comment: Oh you're right, completely forgot about the MACOSX_BUNDLE. But even if I replace it it doesn't solve my problem (In fact I did replace it but forgot to mention it)

Comment: Have you more information about the unresolved external symbol ? Is it from the VTK lib or another one ?

Comment: Nope I don't. Don't think it comes from VTK as I don't have the RotateActor.cxx included anymore

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79639/discussion-between-lonni-besancon-and-caduchon).